# sql query help - multiple responses into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope I can describe this well enough for you to get what I need. I have a table with questionnaire responses, columns are:

```
cust_id
question_number
response 
datetimestamp
```

So my table looks like this:

| cust_id | question_no | response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | YES |
| 1234 | 2 | NO |
| 1234 | 3 | TAKEN |
| 1234 | 4 | NOT GIVEN |
| 4567 | 1 | NO |
| 4567 | 3 | NOT TAKEN |
| 8888 | 2 | YES |
| 8888 | 4 | GIVEN |

basically i need a query which will give me each cust_id and each question and response - like this:

| cust_id | question_1 | response_1 | question_2 | response_2 | question_3 | response_3 | question_4 | response_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | YES | 2 | NO | 3 | taken | 4 | not given |
| 4567 | 1 | NO | 3 | NOT TAKEN |  |  |  |  |
| 8888 | 2 | YES | 4 | GIVEN |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please review the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: You need to explain further

Comment: You need to use the PIVOT function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server/15745076#15745076) for an example

Answer (score 0):

If you union the questions to the responses, then you can pivot them.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      cust_id
    , [col] = CONCAT('response_', 
                     row_number() over (partition by cust_id 
                                        order by question_no))
    , concat(response, null) as [value]
    FROM customer_question_responses
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      cust_id
    , [col] = CONCAT('question_', 
                     row_number() over (partition by cust_id 
                                        order by question_no))
    , concat(question_no, null) as [value]
    FROM customer_question_responses
) Src
PIVOT
(
  MAX([value]) 
  FOR [Col] IN (
   [question_1], [response_1], 
   [question_2], [response_2], 
   [question_3], [response_3], 
   [question_4], [response_4]
  ) 
) Pvt
ORDER BY cust_id
```

| cust_id | question_1 | response_1 | question_2 | response_2 | question_3 | response_3 | question_4 | response_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | YES | 2 | NO | 3 | TAKEN | 4 | NOT GIVEN |
| 4567 | 1 | NO | 3 | NOT TAKEN | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 8888 | 2 | YES | 4 | GIVEN | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bee294cb8a1873809c1b4cb206ba2f11)*

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to pivot using conditional aggregation than using `PIVOT` if you have multiple columns to pivot.

In this case, just add a row-number and conditionally aggregate on that:

```sql
SELECT
  t.cust_id,
  question_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.question_no END),
  response_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.response END),
  question_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.question_no END),
  response_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.response END),
  question_3 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 3 THEN t.question_no END),
  response_3 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 3 THEN t.response END),
  question_4 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 4 THEN t.question_no END),
  response_4 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 4 THEN t.response END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY question_no)
    FROM YourTable t
) t;
```